# Strange error c2660 "function does not take 1 arguments"

Tags: c++, default-value, derived-class, base-class

My base class has this function

```
LRESULT CBaseClass::OnTestFunction(WPARAM id, LPARAM=0)
{
...
}
```

When the derived class calls this function

```
OnTestFunction(nId);
```

I get an error C2660 :  "function does not take 1 arguments".

Why is that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the default value in the class definition in the header file.

```
class CBaseClass {
    ....
    LRESULT OnTestFunction(WPARAM id, LPARAM=0);
    ....
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The default value should be in the class definition:

```
class CBaseClass {
    LRESULT OnTestFunction(WPARAM id, LPARAM=0);
};
```

so that the derived class can see that signature and the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be there a name of the parameter in the signature? Like:

```
LRESULT CBaseClass::OnTestFunction(WPARAM id, LPARAM optional = 0)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct for the header file, but how would you use it without name in the body of the method? Or is it possible to specify a default-value parameter for base class method without name, expecting that someone who will override it and intent to use that parameter will provide name later?

Comment: Obviously, you'd only omit the name if you weren't using the parameter anyway.